# libreoffice writers2latex option via CLI

Tags: latex, libreoffice

LibreOffice Writer offers a way to export documents as LaTeX. However, I need to process many files in batch using the corresponding terminal commands:

```
soffice --convert-to tex my-file.odt --headless
```

or

```
soffice --convert-to tex:org.openoffice.da.writer2latex my-file.odt --headless
```

This is working fine until I try to follow the instructions (see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/doc1.6/user-manual7.html and [enter link description here](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/doc1.6/user-manual12.html#bkmRefHeading45691948605489)) on how to pass certain options to the converter:

```
soffice --convert-to tex:org.openoffice.da.writer2latex:inputencoding=utf8 my-file.odt --headless
```

The command above should lead to the tex-code containing the line, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` but in fact I get `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}`. Using the Writer GUI the encoding and many other options can be set for export and lead to the expected results.

Since writer2latex has no vivid developer community I hope to solve the issue here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the mentioned problems maybe a version conflict between LibreOffice (v6) and w2l (v1.0.2, v1.4.0, v1.2.1, v1.6.1). Using the current alpha version 1.9.3 of w2l works at least for the jar file:

```
java -jar /some/path/writer2latex19/writer2latex.jar -latex \
        -use_color=false \
        -backend=pdftex \
        -inputencoding=utf8 \
        -multilingual=false \
        -float_figures=true \
        -ignore_hard_page_breaks=true \
        -ignore_double_spaces=true \
        -no_preamble=true \
        -formatting=ignore_most \
your.odt
```